# chromadb Collection.add(Includes=[""]) giving error

Tags: python, chromadb

I am new to chromadb. Learning it first time. Just a simple code is here:

```
 collection.add(
    documents=["This is a document", "This is another document"],
    metadatas=[{"source": "test_source", "page": 1},{"source": "test_source2", "page": 2}, ],
    ids=["id1", "id2"],
    include=['distances', 'metadatas', 'embeddings', 'documents'],
)
```

I am getting error  `TypeError: Collection.add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include'`. Need some help, how to show embeddings in chromadb. I have installed latest version.